# Reading single Row of CSV per Loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, loops, csv, dynamic

Python3.7
CSV

I've reframed this question to make it more apparent - I'm trying to access a particular line from a CSV on each pass in a loop.

So on the first Loop take Row 1

The second time the loop comes around take Row 2

Third time the loop comes around take Row 3 from CSV

**test.csv:**

```
How To Write Your First Article Heading,
Here's The Important Second Article Heading,
Three is The Magic Number,
```

**script:**

```
import csv

name = 'Article Heading'


for i in range(3):

    with open ('test.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for i in range(3):
            try:
                csv_row = ' '.join(next(reader))
            except StopIteration:
                break

            articletitle = (name + ' | ' + csv_row)
            print(articletitle)

print('THEN WE GO OFF AND DO SOMETHING BEFORE GOING BACK FOR THE NEXT ROW IN THE CSV')
```

**OUTPUT OF ABOVE:**

```
Article Heading | How To Write Your First Article Heading 
Article Heading | Here's The Important Second Article Heading 
Article Heading | Three is The Magic Number 
Article Heading | How To Write Your First Article Heading 
Article Heading | Here's The Important Second Article Heading 
Article Heading | Three is The Magic Number 
Article Heading | How To Write Your First Article Heading 
Article Heading | Here's The Important Second Article Heading 
Article Heading | Three is The Magic Number 
THEN WE GO OFF AND DO SOMETHING BEFORE GOING BACK FOR THE NEXT ROW IN THE CSV
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
Article Heading | How To Write Your First Article Heading 
THEN WE GO OFF AND DO SOMETHING BEFORE GOING BACK FOR THE NEXT ROW IN THE CSV
Article Heading | Here's The Important Second Article Heading 
THEN WE GO OFF AND DO SOMETHING BEFORE GOING BACK FOR THE NEXT ROW IN THE CSV
Article Heading | Three is The Magic Number
THEN WE GO OFF AND DO SOMETHING BEFORE GOING BACK FOR THE NEXT ROW IN THE CSV
```

If people think I have this completely messed up I'm open to harsh criticism. I promise I've searched for a solution but no joy.

Comment: Hi ColumnS and welcome to stackoverflow. Could you edit your question to focus more on a problem and stripe all introduction/distraction parts? (https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).
I will be eager to look into your question once it's stripped to only necessary parts (now it's quite hard for me to go through it) :)

Comment: thanks @puchal - I've stripped it back a little to leave only the context of the question and the problem as best I can describe in laymans terms - appreciate your assistance

Comment: Instead of describing everything it words, give a few lines of expected input and output as examples.  As it is, the description sounds like you want to iterate through the columns of the CSV data, but are calling them rows??

Comment: Thank you so much @puchal - I really appreciate it. Your analysis has allowed me to phrase my question better and I can show it in terms of what you wrote - rather than my messy explanation: 
Editing above:

Comment: Thanks @Mark Tolonen - duly noted and edited above

Answer (score 0):

the problem you have is that to read the csv file you use `list(csv.reader(infile))`

`csv.reader(infile)` is an iterator and would go line by line in your file.

If I understood your question correctly you can tackle your problem in two ways.

One is having a loop using `for _ in range(5)` to go through loop 5 times:

```py
with open ('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            csv_row = ' '.join(next(reader))
            print(csv_row)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

(You need to handle `StopIteration` exception if the csv file has less then 5 lines)

Or you could go through each line of csv file and break after 5th iteration of the loop:

```py
with open ('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 5:
            break
        row = ' '.join(line)
        print(row)
```

In this solution there is no need of handling any exception but if you want to break loop after 5th iterations you need to have some if statement to see which iteration is currently ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through rows is straightforward.  In your test case you don't even really need the csv module, but I'll use your test case:

Code:

```
import csv

name = 'Article Heading'

# newline='' should be used per documentation for csv.reader.
with open ('test.csv', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        articletitle = name + ' | ' + row[0]
        print(articletitle)
        print('THEN WE GO OFF AND DO SOMETHING BEFORE GOING BACK FOR THE NEXT ROW IN THE CSV')
```

Output:

```
Article Heading | How To Write Your First Article Heading
THEN WE GO OFF AND DO SOMETHING BEFORE GOING BACK FOR THE NEXT ROW IN THE CSV
Article Heading | Here's The Important Second Article Heading
THEN WE GO OFF AND DO SOMETHING BEFORE GOING BACK FOR THE NEXT ROW IN THE CSV
Article Heading | Three is The Magic Number
THEN WE GO OFF AND DO SOMETHING BEFORE GOING BACK FOR THE NEXT ROW IN THE CSV
```

*EDIT*

To iterate over columns, read all the data and transpose columns to rows:

test.csv:

```
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```

Code:

```py
import csv

name = 'Article Heading'

# newline='' should be used per documentation for csv.reader.
with open ('test.csv', newline='') as file:
    rows = list(csv.reader(file))

columns = zip(*rows) # transpose rows/columns

for column in columns:
    for item in column:
        article_title = f'{name} | {item}'
        print(article_title)
```

Output:

```
Article Heading | 1
Article Heading | 2
Article Heading | 3
Article Heading | 4
Article Heading | 5
Article Heading | 6
Article Heading | 7
Article Heading | 8
Article Heading | 9
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark Tolonen, really appreciate taking time to look at it. Your suggested code is really close to what I'm trying to achieve but maybe I confused things even further - though in my understanding if I run the above it will print the output you gave, but the next time the loop comes around it will print that same output again. I think what I'm trying to get is to have {code}articletitle = name + ' | ' + row[*]{code} So that the first time round it prints row 0, (then I take row 0 and use it in the script) then next time I want to use the same piece of code but this time acting on row 1.

Comment: @ColumnS So you are calling columns rows.  A concrete example would help, but to iterate over columns you can read in the whole file and transpose the data.  I'll update with an example.